# How TO Get Refresh Token using Google Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-contacts-api, service-accounts, refresh-token

I want to generate the refresh token using a Google service account. By using the refresh token I'll generate the access token and call the Google APIs. Please do let me know. Thanks

Comment: It's a strange use case... But anyway, what's your language?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, javascript

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, Can u please share the steps on how to get a refresh token from the service account. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here an example with the default service account:

```
    const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
    const auth = new GoogleAuth()
    const adc = await auth.getApplicationDefault()
    const refresh_token = await adc.credential.getAccessToken()
                 .then(value => value.res.data.refresh_token);
```

Tune this code as you want!

Comment: But where are we passing the service account details like private, clientId, etc?. Is there any API to generate the refresh token using a service account?

Comment: The easiest for me is to define the service account file as env var, even in the nodeJS and before calling the `getApplicationDefault()`, like this `process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/key.json";`